# Online service for Ruby code highlighting with html output

Tags: ruby, syntax-highlighting

I write articles about ROR with a lot of Ruby code inside.

I need an online service such as [tohtml.com](http://www.tohtml.com/ruby/) to make my code insertions beatiful. This resource fine, but it is quite simple and not allow to show numbers of line. Of course output should be in HTML format.

Could you help me?

Comment: On Github, you can create gists (https://gist.github.com/).  Once created, there is some embed code that you can add to you post.

Comment: Thanks, but i need plain html output that i can paste in my post. The code should be like in this [article](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/algorithm/124258/)

Comment: It's not an online service, but if you have the ability to add scripts to your blogging platform, this may work for you:  http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

Answer (score 0):

it called http://pygments.appspot.com/
Ryan Bates made a [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque) to shouw howto highlight a ruby code anysc with Redis. background processing is really useful for such kind of tasks.

Comment: I want to get code as here http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/algorithm/124258/. With numbers of line at right.